# Solutions to $w_x=CA_x$, $w_y=CA_y$ other than $w=f(A)$ and $C=f'(A)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, partial-derivative

Let $R$ be an integral domain of characteristic zero and let $A=A(x,y) \in R[x,y]$ with $\deg(A) \geq 1$ (total degree).

Assume that there exist $w=w(x,y),C=C(x,y) \in R[x,y]$ such that
$w_x=CA_x$ and $w_y=CA_y$. The subscripts denote partial derivatives, of course.

> Can one find the exact form of such $w$ and $C$?

Notice that a possible solution is as follows: $w=\sum_{i=0}^{m}\lambda_iA^i$, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lambda_i \in R$, $1 \leq i \leq m$ (in short, $w=f(A)$, for some $f \in R[T]$), and $C=\sum_{i=1}^{m}i\lambda_iA^{i-1}=f'(A)$.
Indeed, $w_x=f'(A)A_x=CA_x$ and $w_y=f'(A)A_y=CA_y$.

> Is it true that a solution is necessarily of the form $w=f(A)$, $C=f'(A)$?

**Observations:**

**(i)** $w_x=CA_x$ implies that $w_{xy}=C_yA_x+CA_{xy}$, 
so $w_{xy}-CA_{xy}=C_yA_x$.

**(ii)** $w_y=CA_y$ implies that $w_{yx}=C_xA_y+CA_{yx}$, 
so $w_{yx}-CA_{yx}=C_xA_y$.

Since $w_{xy}=w_{yx}$ and $A_{xy}=A_{yx}$, we get that $C_yA_x=C_xA_y$.

Also observe that $C_yA_x=C_xA_y$ implies that
$C_yw_x=C_y(CA_x)=C(C_yA_x)=C(C_xA_y)=C_x(CA_y)=C_xw_y$.

Perhaps knowing that $C_yA_x=C_xA_y$ and $C_yw_x=C_xw_y$ may help solve my question.

**Remark:** I am especially interested in a non-normal integral domain $R$ of characteristic zero such as $R=\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$ or $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$,
though I am not sure if this should affect the answer.

Any hints and comments are welcome!